# Python: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'childGenerator'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My code works perfectly to parse some HTML tables, but it fails on this table with the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'childGenerator'` and I'm not sure why because it appears identical. Maybe it's the underlying HTML code that messes it up?

Here's a table I can successfully parse:

[image]

and it's HTML code:

```
<html>
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Sector 2 has updated its quota listings.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Please see below.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Thanks,<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style='color:#DE3500'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Wednesday, May 21, 2014 2:00 PM<br><b>To:</b> David Leveille<br><b>Subject:</b> Corrected NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:#1F487E'>AVAILABLE QUOTA FY 2014</span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'><o:p></o:p></span></p><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="75%" style='width:75.3%'><tr><td width=276 style='width:207.35pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>ID <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=202 style='width:151.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Available Quota <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Live Weight Pounds <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=182 style='width:136.65pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Price <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=108 style='width:81.05pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Date Posted <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td width=276 style='width:207.35pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1724<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=202 style='width:151.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>GOM BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>DABS<br>GOM YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>2328<br>445<br>3007<br>850<br>3101<br>1995<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=182 style='width:136.65pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$9,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=108 style='width:81.05pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=276 style='width:207.35pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1578<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=202 style='width:151.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GB BB<br>GB YT<br>SNE BB<br>SNE YT<br>GOM BB<br>Whake<br>POLL<br>RED<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>538<br>1755<br>243<br>490<br>153<br>3965<br>2727<br>9227<br>15060<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=182 style='width:136.65pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.00<br>$0.20<br>$1.00<br>$0.45<br>$0.50<br>$0.15<br>$0.20<br>$0.01<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=108 style='width:81.05pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=276 style='width:207.35pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>310<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=202 style='width:151.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>DABS<br>WHAKE<br>POLL<br>RED<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>825<br>9033<br>12419<br>3120<br>65234<br>76610<br>2121<br>7285<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=182 style='width:136.65pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>15,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=108 style='width:81.05pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr style='height:23.25pt'><td width=276 style='width:207.35pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>347<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=202 style='width:151.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>SNE BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>8,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=182 style='width:136.65pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.50<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=108 style='width:81.05pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/7<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=276 style='width:207.35pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878A<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=202 style='width:151.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<br>GB BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>GOM YT<br>SNE YT<br>POLL<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=119 style='width:89.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6188<br>635<br>3916<br>7873<br>6762<br>3358<br>9776<br>271<br>186550<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=182 style='width:136.65pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
```

And here's the table that I fail at parsing for reasons I don't know:

[image]

and its corresponding HTML code:

```
<html>
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Please see quota listings below.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style='color:#DE3500'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Wednesday, November 06, 2013 1:46 PM<br><b>To:</b> David Leveille<br><b>Subject:</b> NEFS 2 Available quota 11/6<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:16.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:#1F487E'>AVAILABLE QUOTA 2013</span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'> <o:p></o:p></span></p><table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="77%" style='width:77.28%;border:none;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt'><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>ID <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Available Quota <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=330 style='width:247.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Live Weight Pounds <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=145 style='width:108.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Price <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=86 style='width:64.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Date Posted <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1767<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>DABS<br>GOM WINTER<br>GOM YELLOWTAIL<br>WHITE HAKE<br>GREYSOLE<br>POLLOCK<br>REDS<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=330 style='width:247.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>8,334<br>1,586<br>1,494<br>11,722<br>6,191<br>476<br>959<br>3,886<br>8,825<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=145 style='width:108.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.50<br>$1.30<br>$0.45<br>$0.15<br>$0.90<br>$0.30<br>$1.00<br>$0.01<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=86 style='width:64.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>11/4<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>001<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM HADD<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=330 style='width:247.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>859<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=145 style='width:108.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.25<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=86 style='width:64.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>10/30<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1153<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM YellowTail<br>SNE Winter<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=330 style='width:247.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6,000<br>8,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=145 style='width:108.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.80<br>$0.45<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=86 style='width:64.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>10/29<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>160<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
```

And here's my relevant code:

```
def celltext(cell):
    textlist=[]
    y = cell.find('span')
    for a in y.childGenerator(): 
        if isinstance(a, NavigableString):
            textlist.append(str(a))
    return (textlist)

for row in table.find_all('tr'):    
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    try:
        if columns[0].get_text().strip()!='ID':# skip header
            print("First Column:", columns[0].get_text().strip())
            quota = columns[1].get_text().strip()
            print(quota)
            Quota = celltext(columns[1]) 
            Weight =  celltext(columns[2])
```

The code fails on the line `Quota = celltext(columns[1])`. I know the `NoneType` error is a result of a function working on an object or value that is `None` but I can't understand why my code runs perfectly on several HTML tables but fails miserably on this one.

Any help explaining this would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens on the 3rd line of the `celltext` function:

```
y = cell.find('span')
for a in y.childGenerator():   <--
```

Most likely, `y` is None because 'span' was not found. Print what is in `cell`. If there is no 'span' there, you will want to add a condition in `celltext`.

Comment: That does make sense...but when I printed `columns[1]` I got `<td style="width:121.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt" width="162"><p class="MsoNormal"><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br/>GOM HADD<br/>DABS<br/>GOM WINTER<br/>GOM YELLOWTAIL<br/>WHITE HAKE<br/>GREYSOLE<br/>POLLOCK<br/>REDS<o:p></o:p></span></p></td>`  so we can see there is a `span` in there... Sorry for being a noob with HTML btw

Comment: What about `columns[2]`? What you really need to do actually is open a Python console, import beautifulsoup, put what you just pasted above in a variable `cell`, then use `cell.find('span')` on it. That is how debugging/testing works.

Comment: Indeed I just tested it and it found the span, so I suppose the problem is in `columns2`. Also, printing the value of `cell` will help more.

Comment: `columns[2]` also has `span` in it. I am using the Python console. I am also using BeautifulSoup, I didn't think it was necessary to put that piece of my code into my question. My problem is that I don't understand why my code works on one table and fails on an almost identical table.

Comment: One of your rows misses a span where you expect it, that is 99.9% sure. Just print the value of `cell` before the program fails.

Comment: I ran your code on the second table and it worked fine: > ```First Column: 1767
GOM CODGOM HADDDABSGOM WINTERGOM YELLOWTAILWHITE HAKEGREYSOLEPOLLOCKREDS
First Column: 001
GOM HADD
First Column: 1153
GOM YellowTailSNE Winter
First Column: 160```. You may have reused variables carrying the wrong value. Try to put your main loop in a function.

Answer (score 0):

I copied an pasted your code with the content of the second table and it worked fine:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<html>
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Please see quota listings below.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style='color:#DE3500'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Wednesday, November 06, 2013 1:46 PM<br><b>To:</b> David Leveille<br><b>Subject:</b> NEFS 2 Available quota 11/6<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:16.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:#1F487E'>AVAILABLE QUOTA 2013</span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'> <o:p></o:p></span></p><table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="77%" style='width:77.28%;border:none;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt'><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>ID <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Available Quota <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=330 style='width:247.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Live Weight Pounds <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=145 style='width:108.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Price <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=86 style='width:64.5pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Date Posted <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1767<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>DABS<br>GOM WINTER<br>GOM YELLOWTAIL<br>WHITE HAKE<br>GREYSOLE<br>POLLOCK<br>REDS<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=330 style='width:247.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>8,334<br>1,586<br>1,494<br>11,722<br>6,191<br>476<br>959<br>3,886<br>8,825<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=145 style='width:108.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.50<br>$1.30<br>$0.45<br>$0.15<br>$0.90<br>$0.30<br>$1.00<br>$0.01<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=86 style='width:64.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>11/4<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>001<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM HADD<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=330 style='width:247.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>859<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=145 style='width:108.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.25<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=86 style='width:64.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>10/30<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1153<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM YellowTail<br>SNE Winter<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=330 style='width:247.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6,000<br>8,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=145 style='width:108.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.80<br>$0.45<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=86 style='width:64.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>10/29<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=66 style='width:49.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>160<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=162 style='width:121.5pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";"""

table = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def celltext(cell):
    textlist=[]
    y = cell.find('span')
    for a in y.childGenerator(): 
        if isinstance(a, NavigableString):
            textlist.append(str(a))
    return (textlist)

for row in table.find_all('tr'):    
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    try:
        if columns[0].get_text().strip()!='ID':# skip header
            print("First Column:", columns[0].get_text().strip())
            quota = columns[1].get_text().strip()
            print(quota)
            Quota = celltext(columns[1]) 
            Weight =  celltext(columns[2])
    except:
        print("Error on this row?")  # you may want to print the row content
```

> First Column: 1767
> GOM CODGOM HADDDABSGOM WINTERGOM YELLOWTAILWHITE HAKEGREYSOLEPOLLOCKREDS
> Error on this row?
> First Column: 001
> GOM HADD
> Error on this row?
> First Column: 1153
> GOM YellowTailSNE Winter
> Error on this row?
> First Column: 160
>
> Error on this row?

But in any case, the script will end with an error if there is no 'span' to be found because `cell.find('span')` will be `None`, so it cannot have a `childGenerator` attribute. You may want to add an exception in case there is no 'span'.

The problem may come from the fact that you are running the same script twice in the same session and variables could be overridden unexpectedly. Try to put your main loop in a function (with the html text as parameter) instead.